# How can I clean up these complex buttons?

Tags: android, android-button

We have an Android app which has a view with a row of buttons at the top. Each of the three buttons in the row is made up of an icon inside a circle with the text that describes it below the circle (something like this wireframe, though I picked the icons at random since I'm not allowed to share the actual ones):

[image: Our icon bar]

Originally, these buttons were designed having the icon, circle background, and circle border as a raster image (with multiple densities, as required) and the following code (repeated three times, once for each button):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button1Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button1Text"
        android:src="@drawable/button1Image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/button1Text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have been given the task of modernizing this code, because the icons we are using are actually all originally vector icons (from the Material Design Library) and we should be able to just use the vectors and not need to worry about rasterizing and pixel density.

What I would like to do is remove the circle from the icon itself (so I can use the Material vector icons without modifying them) and have the button background add the circle. (This also allows me to change the color of the circle based on the app variant without having many different sets of images.)

I have seen many examples of how to make a circular button with both the icon and the text inside it, but I cannot seem to figure out how to make a single button that looks the way I want.

How can I make a nice reusable component that takes the vector icon and text and gives me this layout for each button?

---

**CLARIFICATION**: What I would like to do here is remove the circles from the icons and have the circle be the background of the button. I know I can do that with two buttons, one for the text with no background and one for the image with a background, but I want to know if there is a way I can do this with a single XML tag since I have a whole bunch of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use button and set icon of button using `android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon"`.

Here is full code:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

**Updated**:
What you can do in that case is to create custom component and set top icon from there. Here are steps I tried and it worked:

1. Create `attrs.xml` file in `res/values folder` and topIcon as attribute name:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <attr name="topIcon" format="reference" />

       <declare-styleable name="CustomButton">
           <attr name="topIcon" />
       </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Create `CustomButton` class and add circle drawable as background layer using [LayerDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable):

   ```
   public class CustomButton extends Button {
       public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
           if (attrs != null) {
               TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomButton);
               Drawable topIcon = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomButton_topIcon);

               LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(
                       new Drawable[]{getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle), topIcon}
               );

               setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, layerDrawable, null, null);
               typedArray.recycle();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use created component from layout file and set `topIcon` attribute. Also, as we extend Button class, you can use any other attributes of it. Make sure package name is correct:

   ```
      <com.natigbabayev.experimental.CustomButton
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Hello World!"
               app:topIcon="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>
   ```

Comment: You've mentioned that "remove the circles from the icons and have the circle be the background of the button". In that case, instead of setting `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`, you can set background as circle drawable which you have already created.

Answer (score 0):

use [Material Button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/); for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        android:text="@string/text_button_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:cornerRadius="80dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black_36dp"
        app:iconPadding="6dp"/>

</layout>
```

Comment: The design guide for Material Button explicitly says not to use it in the way that my app's buttons are designed - with the image above the text. (I would like to update this app to full material design, but we're not quite there yet.)

Comment: @MosheKatz updated my answer; the label just needs to be placed inside the button. the mere difference is, is that the icons is always beside the text instead above it; one could also create a custom button, which extends `MaterialButton`.